# Why is visual studio double indenting on a double return?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting

I've started getting the following behaviour a lot in visual studio:

1. Press enter
2. Caret inserts a new line, indent is set appropriatelly
3. Press enter (again)
4. Caret inserts a new line, indent is '1 in'

It looks like this:

https://gph.is/2FjXUnp

I'm pretty sure it didn't used to do this and I'm noticing it in a lot of places - mid function or elsewhere. Sometimes it doesn't require a double enter - as soon as I hit return it begins the indent too deep. If I reformat it corrects but obviously this is quite irritating to do.

The example above is based on a minimal reduction of code to try and get it to reproduce. If I remove the comments and or the method it does not happen.

I suspect I've inadvertently enabled some option or something but can't understand where. Can anybody provide some clues?

VS21015 with resharper (behaviour exists with resharper suspended)

Comment: I'm going to assume that you looked, but do you have any other VS extensions installed that might account for this? If yes, have you updated those extensions?